# Problema al configurar notificaciones remotas

Tags: ios, swift

Soy nuevo en programación en Swift y llevo un tiempo intentando implementar el sistema de notificaciones de Google GCM, he seguido los pasos pero me da la sensación de que hay un paso que no he llevado a cabo y no sé como hacerlo. En la guía de Google dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no me equivoco en el punto c me indica que introduzca el código del APNs en el diccionario. ¿Podrías indicarme como hacerlo así como otro consejo a la hora de implementar este sistema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.